# Update two identical database schemas at the same time

Tags: java, database, hibernate, database-schema

I've got an Oracle database that has two schemas in it which are identical.  One is essentially the "on" schema, and the other is the "off" schema.  We update data in the off schema and then switch the schemas behind an alias which our production servers use.  Not a great solution, but it's what I've been given to work with.

My problem is that there is a separate application that will now be streaming data to the database (also handed to me) which is currently only updating the alias, which means it is only updating the "on" schema at any given time.  That means that when the schemas get switched, all the data from this separate application vanishes from production (the schema it is in is now the "off" schema).

This application is using Hibernate 3.3.2 to update the database. There's Spring 3.0.6 in the mix as well, but not for the database updates.  Finally, we're running on Java 1.6.

Can anyone point me in a direction to updating both "on" and "off" schemas simultaneously that does not involve rewriting the whole DAO layer using Spring JDBC to load two separate connection pools?  I have not been able to find anything about getting hibernate to do this.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: wait, you're _toggling_ between databases?  Why?  And how often?  This strikes me as more problematic than anything else...

Comment: That was my question exactly when I was handed this.  The data loads are huge, take multiple hours a piece, and require testing before exposed to production - so we execute a load on the "off" schema (about 4-8 hours), test it, then point the database connection alias to the "off" schema to make it the "on" schema, making it live to production. This streaming data thing is supposed to replace the "massive load" model.

Comment: And yes, it is very problematic. Trust me - you have no idea.  But, you work with what you've got (until you can convince the higher ups to lay out money to change it).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be updating two seperate databases this way, *especially* from the **application's** point of view. All it should know/care about is whether or not the data is there, not having to mess with two *separate* databases.

Frankly, this sounds like you may need to purchase an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool.  Even if you can't get it to update the 'on' schema from the 'off' one (fast enough to be practical), you will *likely* be able to use it to keep the two in sync (mirror changes from 'on' to 'off').

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page, the data is coming from a third party, and gets loaded into the off schema.  Once it is tested in the off schema, we switch it to "on", then perform the same load on the newly "off" schema. Then we start loading new data into the "off" schema.  Wash, rinse, repeat.  Using a new architectural tool isn't going to help me in this case, due to time and cash constraints.  I just need a quick way to copy an insert to both schemas from the new feed, preferably with Hibernate since that is what's used by the code I was handed.

Answer (score 0):

[HA-JDBC](http://ha-jdbc.sourceforge.net/) is a replicating JDBC Driver we investigated for a short while. It will automatically replicate all inserts and updates, and distribute all selects. There are other database specific master-slave solutions as well.

On the other hand, I wouldn't recommend doing this for 4-8 hour procedures. Better lock the database before, update one database, and then backup-restore a copy, and then unlock again.